# Performance: List.get(index) vs List[index]

Tags: apex, list, performance, collection

I want to know which approach is better in Salesforce when getting element from list.

Is this faster?

```
myList.get(0);
```

Or is this faster?

```
myList[0];
```

Using large list which above statement is more efficient?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The following methodology may be somewhat faulty but demonstrates a large difference. The `get` approach is more than 4 times slower.

**Square Brackets**

```
List<Integer> numbers = new List<Integer>();
for (Integer i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) numbers.add(i);

Integer x;
Long start = Datetime.now().getTime();
for (Integer i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) x = numbers[i];
system.debug(Datetime.now().getTime() - start); // 1233
```

**Get Method**

```
List<Integer> numbers = new List<Integer>();
for (Integer i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) numbers.add(i);

Integer x;
Long start = Datetime.now().getTime();
for (Integer i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) x = numbers.get(i);
system.debug(Datetime.now().getTime() - start); // 5065
```

Comment: this is good news as the `get()` takes 4 more chars to type :-)

Comment: Interesting. A related article http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5447/is-there-a-difference-between-an-array-and-a-list-in-apex/  Maybe try using a variable to capture the time so the debug statement doesn't alter the time.

Comment: @ChrisFellows There is only one debug statement at the end. There's no way it adds more than `1-2ms`. Actually if you remove the loop between the two statements you get `0`.

Comment: Running Adrian's code with a separate stop variable in execute anonymous my results were 1923/1670/1539/1347 and 7679/9810/8102/8310 so consistent with the "more than 4 times slower". Surprisingly big. And I'm with @crop1645 on the less characters to type (and clearer resulting code).

Comment: @ChrisFellows I think because of the number of calls, my numbers are nanoseconds per request. This is the best profiling mechanism I have come across for `Apex`, but it is definitely quite rudimentary.

Comment: @AdrianLarson - Yup you're right on the debug. I think it might be milliseconds no? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_getTime This is pretty interesting. must be the method call expense.

Comment: @ChrisFellows Yes, the number that is output is milliseconds, but I make 1,000,000 calls. So it ends up telling you nanoseconds per individual get/index call.

Comment: Right you are: / 1000000 to get per call time. So all in all its pretty much a wash.

Comment: @ChrisFellows I'm going to disagree with that statement. A wash is when all things are equal. Using a method that's 5x slower isn't a wash when it happens all over the place. You can easily end up adding 1-2 seconds to a transaction in just a handful of loops. I've seen and written code that would have been crippled by this seemingly insignificant amount of time.

Comment: Well the difference is measured in nanoseconds. For 99.9% of all coding operations involving a get() versus [] call, I believe its more important to be focused on the logic than inching out a few nanoseconds here and there. How often are you looping through millions of records which is what it takes to get into the milliseconds and seconds range. And if you're looping through millions of records you're not doing that synchronously likely. Yes, it happens, just not frequently enough that most people have to be overly concerned about it. Its all relative.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if Salesforce changed its algorithms, but I just tested it, both in my Sandbox and Production, and it turns out the method `List.get()` is almost always faster than **square brackets** `[i]`.

My first attempt, running `List.get()` prior to running square bracket:

```
// Square Brackets vs List.get()
   List<Integer> numbers = new List<Integer>();
   for (Integer i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) numbers.add(i);

   Integer x;

// List.get()
   Long startBracket = Datetime.now().getTime();
   for (Integer i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) x = numbers.get(i);
   System.debug(Datetime.now().getTime() - startBracket); // 1422

// Square Brackets
   Long startGet = Datetime.now().getTime();
   for (Integer i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) x = numbers[i];
   System.debug(Datetime.now().getTime() - startGet); // 1528
```

Then I ran it again. The results:

- get: 1575
- brackets: 1859

Maybe the problem was the execution order? Well, I've inverted it, just in case:

```
// Square Brackets vs List.get()
   List<Integer> numbers = new List<Integer>();
   for (Integer i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) numbers.add(i);

   Integer x;

// Square Brackets
   Long startBracket = Datetime.now().getTime();
   for (Integer i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) x = numbers[i];
   System.debug(Datetime.now().getTime() - startBracket); // 1526

// List.get()
   Long startGet = Datetime.now().getTime();
   for (Integer i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) x = numbers.get(i);
   System.debug(Datetime.now().getTime() - startGet); // 1352
```

I've repeated this test several times, in both Sandbox and Production, with similar results.

Could you guys please repeat the test on your end just in case? Because it seems now it's faster to use `List.get()`.

Comment: I am seeing 1279/2780 and 980/2998 - So I am seeing 2-3 times slower got `.get` in a DE org

Comment: Just to make sure, which one is slower on your end, Eric?

Comment: .get.............

Comment: Just tested it in a Playground (Trailhead) and the `List.get(i)` method was indeed slower than `[i]` on every test. Now I wonder why it differs so much from server to server.

Comment: Yes, there does seem to be some volatility, but I haven't found a definitive answer to why, nor any sort of pattern, so I haven't updated my post.

Comment: List.get(i) is slower just tried it 

get() -> 2252 and
[] -> 1409