# How do I randomize/Shuffle a Map<Id, List<Object>> OR Map<Id, Map<Id, Object>> in Apex?

Tags: apex

I Have used the `Math.Random()` function to give me a random number which I use to get the element on a given Index in the List from a Map **But that doesn't help my requirement!**

What I want is to fill the map in an unordered manner for example:

```
//Project__c is related to Contact 
Map<Id, List<object>> newMap = new Map<Id, List<object>>();
for (Project__c pro : MY_SOQL_QUERY) {
 if (newMap.containsKey(pro.Contact__c)) {
  newMap.get(pro.Contact__c).add(pro);
 }
 else {
  newMap.put(pro.Contact__c, new List<Project__c>{pro});
 }
}
System.debug('========== Map :: ' + newMap.values())
// This will give me :
1.Project__c A
2.Project__c B
3.Project__c C

//What I want is:
1.Project__c B
2.Project__c A
3.Project__c E
4.And so on.....
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Maps are unordered by definition...You seem to be having a bit of an [x-y problem](http://xyproblem.info) here. Can you [edit] your post to give a bit more background about what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: B , A, E .... what is this order?

Comment: @AdrianLarson I basically want to Shuffle the Map.

Comment: @Ratan it's just an Example I want the map to be in Shuffled manner

Comment: You're just reiterating what you think is the right solution to the problem. You're not telling us what the problem itself is that you're trying to solve.

Comment: @d_k You want the list randomized, or the order of the keys?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Okay my problem is that I'm unable to get elements from the map in a Random order since: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer15/release-notes/rn_apex_maps_and_sets_iteration_order.htm

Comment: @sfdcfoxI want to randomize the list

Answer (score 4):

You will probably want to shuffle afterwards, as inserting into random positions of a list is problematic at best. You can start with this class:

```
public class RandomValueWrapper implements Comparable {
    Decimal random;
    public Object value;
    public RandomValueWrapper(Object value) {
        this.value = value;
        random = Math.random();
    }
    public Integer compareTo(Object other) {
        return random - ((RandomSObjectRecord)other).random;
    }
}
```

From there, you can generate a random sort:

```
RandomSObjectWrapper[] wrappers = new RandomSObjectWrapper[0];
for(SObject record: newMap.get(someId).values()) {
    wrappers.add(new RandomSObjectWrapper(record));
}
// Invoke randomness... now!
wrappers.sort();
// Reset list
newMap.get(someId).clear();
for(RandomSObjectWrapper wrapper: wrappers) {
    newMap.get(someId).add((Project__c)wrapper.value);
}
// They are now in random order
```

You could sort the Id values in a random order, a list of SObject (as this example), or however else you feel like.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt you will get the output you stated since every value of newMap is a List itself.

You can obtain the list of keys with newMap.keys() and then grab keys with Math.random(), e.g.

```
List<sObject> keyList = newMap.keys();
Integer counter = keyList.size();
while(counter > 0) {
   sObject currentKey = keyList.[Math.floor(Math.Random()*counter)];
   System.debug(newMap.get(currentKey));
   newMap.remove(currentKey);
   counter--;
}
```

Untested, but I hope you get the gist.

Comment: I think you might need to use `Math.floor()` rather than `Math.rint()` because the latter can possibly return a value equal to `counter`, which would lead to an out-of-bounds error. I also believe that `somelist[index]` is more performant than `somelist.get(index)`. Other than that, I like this answer. +1 from me.

Comment: @Derek You're right about the performance issue. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/112502/performance-list-getindex-vs-listindex/112503#112503

Comment: @DerekF thank you for the suggestions, I have updated my post!